# Unquote HTML entities twice in an XML transformation

Tags: xslt

I tried to convert a Jiira ticket XML export to text with an XML transformation. The XML code contains comment elements with quoted HTML entities and elements.

### Elements

For example a new line is written in the XML export as.

```
&lt;br/&gt;
```

When I output this with the following XSL code:

```
<xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

I get the HTML element:

```
<br>
```

But I need to output a new line.

So I tried this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(., '&lt;br/&gt;', '&#xa;')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

This works, but just for the 'br' element.

### Entities

The same applies to entities. An arrow is quoted this way:

```
--&amp;gt;
```

With disable-output-escaping I get this:

```
--&gt;
```

But I need this:

```
-->
```

Which means that I have to unquote twice.  How can this be done in XSLT?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please post a small example of your XML input, and the expected result of the transformation (as code). -- Also please indicate XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot in plain XSLT (unless you implement an HTML parser in XSLT).  You have to either 1) preprocess your input to transform the lexical HTML to XML elements, 2) postprocess your output, or 3) use an extension function to parse the HTML from within XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get away with

```
<xsl:preserve-space elements="*" />
```

If the source content already has the spaces that you want.

If you want to modify the source it gets a little bit more tricky.

If you only have XSL 1.0, then the best way would simply by to apply two transformations, one to unescape and the other to do white-space processing.

If you have XSL 2.0, then you probably have Saxon, which means you can use an extension function like [parse](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/functions/saxon/parse.html).

Parse would allow you to evaluate the string content as a node result which can then be passed on to template processing normally.  For example take this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <example>
    <content>&lt;br&gt;
        This &lt;i&gt;is&lt;/i&gt; html
        &lt;/br&gt;
    </content>
</example>
```

And this stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <output>
            <xsl:variable name="PREPROCESSED" select="saxon:parse(/example/content)"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$PREPROCESSED" mode="postprocess"/>
        </output>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="postprocess">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="postprocess"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="i" mode="postprocess">
        <b><xsl:apply-templates select="."/></b>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Will yield:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><output xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"><br>
        This <b>is</b> html
        </br></output>
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that the downside of this approach is that it only works if the html is effectively xhtml, otherwise it won't parse.

Comment: You explain how to output `<`, when the input is `&lt;`. My question was how to output `<`, when the input is `&amp;lt;`.

Comment: Your first example was only singly escaped. This solution should work for that issue no?  Is everything double escaped?  You should post an example xml and what you want the result to look like, Like @michael.hor257k asked, as well as saying if you want an XSL 1 or 2 solution.

Comment: First Jiira quotes a `>` for HTML as `&gt;` and second during the XML export to `&amp;gt;`. In my XML-to-text transformation I need to get the original character `>`.

Comment: select="replace($html,'&amp;gt;','>')" will work to fix that case.  If you want more help than that, post a full example.